# RxJS combineLatest add timer to only one observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have two entities, **Games** and **Jackpots**:
Game interface

```
{
    id: string,
    name: string
}
```

Jackpot interface

```
{
    game: string,
    amount: number
}
```

First I have two **observables**, one to get **games** and one to get **jackpots**.
And after getting the data i want to merge the data of **jackpots** into **games** based on **id**. And since the jackpots observale should get the data each seconds i used the operator `timer` to do so. So here's my implementation:

```
private getGames = (category: string): Observable<IGame[]> => {
        return timer(0, 3000).pipe(
            mergeMap(() => combineLatest([this.gameService.getGames(), this.gameService.getJackpots()])),
            map(([games, jackpots]) => {
                return games?.filter(game => game?.categories?.includes(category))?.map(game => {
                    return { ...game, jackpot: jackpots?.find(jackpot => jackpot?.game === game?.id) };
                })
            })
        );
    };
```

This implementation works fine and the data is fetched every 3 seconds. Now as you can see both **Games** and **Jackpots** observable get fetched every 3 seconds, My question is: is there a way to only run the **Jackpots** observable every 3 seconds, and exclude the Games **observable** from that timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Context

[`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) has two important properties:

- it emits every time any of the Observables emits a value.
- it requires all source Observables to emit at least one value.

#### Solution

You can set the `timer` only for the *games* Observable and combine it with the *jackpots* one.

```js
private getGames = (category: string): Observable<IGame[]> => {
  return combineLatest([
    timer(0, 3000).pipe(mergeMap(() => this.gameService.getGames())),
    this.gameService.getJackpots(),
  ]).pipe(
    map(([games, jackpots]) => {
      return games
        ?.filter((game) => game?.categories?.includes(category))
        ?.map((game) => {
          return { ...game, jackpot: jackpots?.find((jackpot) => jackpot?.game === game?.id) };
        });
    })
  );
};
```